# Immediately after the shahadah, what is the phrase used in the chant, (besides Allahu Akbar)?

Tags: arabic, shahada

I am trying to get a better understanding about Islam, for the reasons of not only research, but spirituality. I have been watching videos of people taking the shahadah and I have noticed that after it is completed, the imam leads a chant where the congregation yells "Allahu Akbar".

Here is a video demonstrating this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfNbMUQZiec

Now, what is that phrase that the imam says in between every "Allahu Akbar"?

Pardon my ignorance; I'm just learning the basics at this point.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thank you! Yes, I came across "Takbir" last night, but I was not sure if that was what he was yelling. So, just for clarification, he repetitively says, "Takbir", to which the audience says, "Allahu Akbar"? I find this all very interesting, by the way. I'm happy to be learning more.

Answer (score 2):

The imam and before that -apparently- the audience is saying: "Takbeer"=saying Allahu Akbar الله أكبر. Takbeer or takbir [التكبير](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%83%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B1/) in this -the religious-  context means saying Allah is great in general. 
. While in the linguistic context it my refer to expansion, blowing up or amplification.
The intention for this is to praise Allah! As he guided a former disbeliever to His (the true) path.

**A bit off-topic**:
While we have special takbeer for example at the beginning of the prayer: takbirat al-Ihram (here it appears as a singular, the plural is takbiraat with a prolonged "alif").

We also have takbir al 'id the takbir which might follow some prayers after 'id al-adha or before the two prayers of 'id for both there is more or less no clearly prescribed expression, but both only include saying Allahu akbar beside other formulations.